# react native app on device stops when navigating to second screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a test-app in react-native. With expo start --web the app is running fine in a browser. But when I install the app on my Android phone, and run the app, it stops running as soon as I navigate to the second screen.

There are two screens, a Products screen and a ProductDetails screen, hold together by a NavigationContainer.

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Products from './Products';
import ProductDetails from './ProductDetails';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Products"
            component={Products}
            options={{
               headerTitleAlign: 'center'
             }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="ProductDetails"
            component={ProductDetails}
            options={{
               headerTitleAlign: 'center'
             }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

The first screen is Products. It lists a bunch of furniture products.

Products.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

class Products extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         products: []
      };
    }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.GetAllProducts();
   }

   GetAllProducts() {
         let that = this;

         axios.get('https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/getallproducts')
         .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            that.setState({
               products: response.data
           });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            alert(error.message);
          });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView>
            {
               this.state.products.map((item, index) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                     onPress={() =>
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {
                           itemId: item.id
                         })
                     }
                     key = {item.id}
                     style = {styles.container}>
                     <Text style = {styles.text}>{item.productname}</Text>
                     <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                     <Text>€ {item.price}</Text>
                     <Image source={{ uri: item.picture }} style={{height:120, width:200}}/>
                     <Text style = {styles.text}>
                        {item.name}
                     </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               ))
            }
            </ScrollView>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default Products

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   container: {
      padding: 10,
      marginTop: 3,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      cursor: 'none'
   },
   text: {
      color: '#4f603c'
   }
})
```

The second screen shows the chosen product from the first screen in detail.

ProductDetails.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

class ProductDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedproduct: [],
            prodid: 0
        };
     }
  
     componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            prodid: this.props.route.params.itemId
        }, () => {
            this.GetSelectedProduct();
        });
     }

     GetSelectedProduct() {
        let that = this;

            axios.get('https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/productandalternatives?productid=' + this.state.prodid)
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
              that.setState({
                selectedproduct: response.data
              }, () => {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(that.state.selectedproduct, undefined, 2));
                });
             })
             .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
               alert(error.message);
             });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.selectedproduct.length && (
            <View>
                {
                    this.state.selectedproduct.map((item, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                            key = {item.id} 
                            style = {styles.container}>
                            <Text style = {styles.h3}>{item.productname}</Text>
                            <Text style = {styles.h5}>Product Details</Text>
                            <Text>Name: {item.productname}</Text>
                            <Text>Description: {item.description}</Text>
                            <Text>Price: € {item.price}</Text>
                            <Text>Picture:</Text>
                            <Image source={{ uri: item.picture }} style={{height:240, width:400}}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))
                }
            </View>
            )
        )
    }
}

export default ProductDetails

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    h3: {
        fontSize : '22pt'
    },
    h5: {
        fontSize : '18pt'
    },
    container: {
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        cursor: 'none'
     }
 })
```

The problem resides anywhere inside render() of the second screen. Because, when I omit all code between `<View>` and `</View>`, the app is navigating to the second screen without a problem.

I tested the `axios.get` with an alert and it is returning proper JSON.

Comment: Try only calling `GetSelectedProduct()` inside `componentDidMount()` and add the product ID when you're setting the state in the `GetSelectedProduct()` function

Comment: But I need the prodid in the axios.get. Do you mean I should call setState() once more before the axios.get?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I was mistaken

Answer (score 3):

Just Few Minor Changes

**1.** fontSize should look like this`fontSize: 22`

**2.** You must have to return something in React.

**3.** Always do options chaining while fetching data form API.

**Here is the Solution**

**ProductDetails.js**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity, Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

class ProductDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedproduct: [],
            prodid: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            prodid: this.props.route.params.itemId
        }, () => {
            this.GetSelectedProduct();
        });
    }

    GetSelectedProduct() {
        let that = this;

        axios.get('https://categoriesexpress444.herokuapp.com/productandalternatives?productid=' + this.state.prodid)
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
                that.setState({
                    selectedproduct: response.data
                }, () => {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(that.state.selectedproduct, undefined, 2));
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                alert(error.message);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.selectedproduct?.length ? (
                    <View>
                        {
                            this.state?.selectedproduct?.map((item, index) => (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    key={item?.id}
                                    style={styles.container}>
                                    <Text style={styles.h3}>{item?.productname}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.h5}>Product Details</Text>
                                    <Text>Name: {item?.productname}</Text>
                                    <Text>Description: {item?.description}</Text>
                                    <Text>Price: € {item?.price}</Text>
                                    <Text>Picture:</Text>
                                    <Image source={{ uri: item?.picture }} style={{ height: 240, width: 400 }} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            ))
                        }
                    </View>
                )
                    : <View>
                        <ActivityIndicator />
                    </View>
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ProductDetails

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    h3: {
        fontSize: 22
    },
    h5: {
        fontSize: 18
    },
    container: {
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        cursor: 'none'
    }
})
```

Comment: Great answer, @Harsh! Thanks, the app is running fine now...